# Unable to view the Kubernetes logs in Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to do the log monitoring of Kubernetes cluster using EFK. I got Kibana dashboard but it doesn't show any logs of Kubernetes cluster.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch)  which I followed in my task.By default my dashboard shows like

[image]

After that i changed the index-pattern in dashboard as

[image]

Then it showed as

[image]

My dought is, how Can i view the logs of each and every pod logs in kubernetes cluster?

Could anybody suggest me how to do the log monitoring of kubernetes cluster using EFK?

Comment: Do you have any applications running on your cluster?

Comment: Thanks  @Rico. As of now, Specifically not running any applications in my cluster. but  some containers like Prometheus,Grafana,dashboard are running in kube-system NameSpace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: in order for Fluentd to work, every Kubernetes node must be
>   labeled with beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true, as otherwise
>   the Fluentd DaemonSet will ignore them.

Have you made sure to address this?

Comment: Thank you samhain. As i followed the above mentioned source code link, in my fluentd-es-ds.yaml, `nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready: "true"` is already enabled.

Comment: @GayathriBalipalli please share all the relevant YAMLs, especially fluentd's ConfigMap and your ES service definition

Comment: Hello samhain, Here is the GitHub URL `https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch` which is I followed

Comment: @GayathriBalipalli my bad, I think I missed the part where you updated the index pattern, which you shouldn't have.

Comment: This my config file:`https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-configmap.yaml `. How can i view the logs of my pods in my cluser?. Is there any alternative way for that? Could you please suggest me?

Comment: @GayathriBalipalli see my other comment about the index pattern, above.

Comment: samhain, I didn't get you. Cloud you please specify that once?

Comment: @GayathriBalipalli you said you updated the **index pattern** in the Kibana UI. You shouldn't have. Revert that to `logstash-*`

Comment: @I labeled my worker nodes.after that i run the kibana service as load balancer. I tried to hit kibana url as "http://<master-ip>:<port>".  i  didn't get my dashboard. I checked the logs of elastic-search pod. i am getting the error:`Error from server: Get https://192.168.1.191:10250/containerLogs/kube-system/elasticsearch-logging-0/elasticsearch-logging: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
`. Do have any idea on this issue?